# Using Xtext from command line

Tags: xtext

I'm trying to achieve an **independent command line flavor of Xtext**

- **Input**: grammar file (`grammar.xtext`)
- **Output**: interpreter jar file (`interpreter.jar`)
- **Usage**:

  - `java -jar interpreter.jar input.mydsl`
  - If `input.mydsl` has *incorrect* syntax, interpreter prints `"ERROR"` and exists
  - If `input.mydsl` has *correct* syntax, it should be interpreted.

I look for a **complete** solution based on maven that ideally has the following features:

- small grammar, for instance, calculator of ints and strings

  - interpretation of `5+8*2 -> 21`
  - interpretation of `"abcd"+"ef" -> "abcdef"`
- simple type checker (`5 +"text" -> error`)
- simple maven `pom.xml` that newbies can understand
- easily ported to web (later)

Comment: It surely is possible. A few years ago I did a little repo demonstrating how to embed Xtext in a standalone Java application: [echebbi/standalone-xtext-example](https://github.com/echebbi/standalone-xtext-example). That being said I'm not sure to understand your issue. What is this "independent environment" you're trying to download?

Comment: By independent I mean I was looking for a single `*.jar` file

Comment: So a JAR file containing the whole Xtext framework? Such JAR are available in [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org) (search for the `org.eclipse.xtext` group ID). Does my repository's README answer your questions? If so I'll make it a proper Stack Overflow answer.

Comment: Yes, posting a detailed answer will be of much help, thanks!